Same variable name in two different Typescript files causes an error
First off, I'm using basic typescript as this is just a learning exercise. I am dragging the .js files created from .ts files into HTML pages. Is there a way to allow the same variable name in two different .ts files? Generally I wouldn't expect this behavior. I tried setting "moduleDetection": "force", but while that allows same named variable, it can no longer find function names from button clicks in HTML page objects
Here is the example that throws the "cannot redeclare block-scoped variable..."
app.ts file...
let myString: string = "appFile";

test.ts file...
let myString: string = "testFile";



I am dragging the .js files [...] into HTML pages

That is indeed the old school way of injecting JavaScript. It has a similar effect as concatenating their content, hence the name collision.
If you are fine with merging them as a single variable, a very easy solution is to use the (also old school) var keyword to declare your variable, instead of the (block-scope) let one. var is tolerant to "re-declaration", it does not actually create any new variable (in case of same name), but uses the same one.
On the other hand, if they must remain as separate variables, you have to encapsulate each JS file into their own scope (which you can achieve by forcing them as modules).

it can no longer find function names from button clicks in HTML page objects

To keep your functions visible globally, you should be good by attaching them to the global window object:
window.myFunction = function () {};
// or:
function myFunction2() {}
window.myGlobalFunction2 = myFunction2;

Modern Front-end frameworks (like React, Vue or Angular), and bundling tools (like webpack, Rollup or Vite) help avoiding all these old hassles.

var is working pretty good. ty. I will also now experiment with your other solution
